# Как получить заменяемый символ в replace()

Tags: javascript

У меня есть большая строка с данными, в которой нужно подсветить цифры красным. Я использую replace  и обрамляю каждый символ в span с нужным стилем. Проблема в том, что мне нужно получить тот же символ, что я заменил, чтобы вставить его обратно.

```
data.replace(/\d/g, '<span class="text_red">'+/*вставить символ сюда*/+'</span>'))
```

Как получить заменяемый символ?

Comment: data.replace(/(\d+)/g,'<span class="text_red">$1</span>');

Comment: Всё проще, чем я думал. Благодарю!